# Exporting application

Tags: java, android, export

I am trying to export my app as an .apk file using Eclipse, but during the procedure I can't choose the format so in the end I just get some kind of file which is not apk. What could I do?

Comment: For a dirty solution you can edit the file name and add the extension, after the file is being created.

Comment: I think I tried it, but it may be my bad memory. I'll do it again

Comment: You're telling basically nothing about what's actually happening and what you did. It's gonna be hard helping you. I'd suggest you start here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard